# Windows Forms: Scroll child control when parent is scrolled

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, scroll

I have DataGridView control in my .NET Windows Forms Application. I also place nested control on the client area of the DataGridView, set DataGridView as parent for the nested control and set the location point of the nested control. Schematically:

```
DataGridView parent = new DataGridView(); 
//.....
Control nested = new Control();
nested.Parent = parent;
nested.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

But, when I scroll the contents of the parent GridView using scrollbars, the control isn't moved, i.e. it is not scrolled with the contents of the parent GridView and remains in the upper left corner of the parent GridView. But what if I want, for example, nested control to be always positioned after the first row of the GridView? Is there any trick to synchronize nested control position with the position of the GridView's contents?

Comment: This is not the right way to do it.  DataGridView can already host a control in a cell.  And that will be scrolled.  Use the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92)

Comment: @HansPassant, I've seen this article, but how can I implement something like [nested DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15948/Editable-Nested-DataGrid) using described method? I tried to create and insert a new row, containing only one cell with a custom control, but it seems that DataGridView doesn't allow for a user to have one row with, for example, 5 text cells, and next row with one custom cell. Also I need to hide/show it at runtime, but only for selected rows.

Comment: You are setting the parent of `nested`, which is good. You also need to add `nested` to the child control collection of the cell where you want the control displayed.